# Silverlight is calling completed event more than once

Tags: silverlight, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a silverlight appplication in which i make a call to wcf using basichttpbinding.I have checked all the loops.The problem is that there are certain completed events which are called more than once.I start by handling the loaded event of the webservice.I am not able to find why the event is executed more than once

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean-up your event handlers once they have processed.  See:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/70096/168989.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are wiring up event handlers to the completed event in two separate Silverlight controls or may be twice in the same control? If it's wired up in two separate controls then even though there's only one loaded onto the screen presently, the handlers for both the controls will get activated.